# How do I install Firebase on my Android project using .kts files?

Tags: android, firebase

I have successfully installed Firebase on other projects that use gradle.build files, but now I need to do so on a project that uses .kts files instead.

I carefully followed these instructions:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

When I try to build the project it fails immediately with this output:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services', version: '4.3.15', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.google.gms.google-services:com.google.gms.google-services.gradle.plugin:4.3.15')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.resolveToFoundResult(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:238)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.lambda$resolvePluginRequests$3(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:168)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.CollectionUtils.collect(CollectionUtils.java:207)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.CollectionUtils.collect(CollectionUtils.java:201)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.resolvePluginRequests(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:166)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:101)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.PluginRequestsHandler.handle(PluginRequestsHandler.kt:48)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.StandardKotlinScriptEvaluator$InterpreterHost.applyPluginsTo(KotlinScriptEvaluator.kt:195)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter$ProgramHost.applyPluginsTo(Interpreter.kt:398)
    at Program.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter$ProgramHost.eval(Interpreter.kt:532)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.kt:184)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.StandardKotlinScriptEvaluator.evaluate(KotlinScriptEvaluator.kt:115)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPluginFactory$create$1.invoke(KotlinScriptPluginFactory.kt:51)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPluginFactory$create$1.invoke(KotlinScriptPluginFactory.kt:36)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPlugin.apply(KotlinScriptPlugin.kt:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:44)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:351)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:369)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:350)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:351)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$fromMutableState$1(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:374)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withReplacedLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:345)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:374)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:350)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:72)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:761)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:152)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectLifecycleController.lambda$ensureSelfConfigured$1(ProjectLifecycleController.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$12(StateTransitionController.java:236)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:247)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:235)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$maybeTransitionIfNotCurrentlyTransitioning$9(StateTransitionController.java:196)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.maybeTransitionIfNotCurrentlyTransitioning(StateTransitionController.java:192)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectLifecycleController.ensureSelfConfigured(ProjectLifecycleController.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.ensureConfigured(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:325)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:33)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:50)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.java:64)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:40)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.lambda$prepareProjects$3(VintageBuildModelController.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$12(StateTransitionController.java:236)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:247)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:235)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transitionIfNotPreviously$10(StateTransitionController.java:210)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transitionIfNotPreviously(StateTransitionController.java:206)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.prepareProjects(VintageBuildModelController.java:89)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.getConfiguredModel(VintageBuildModelController.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$withProjectsConfigured$1(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:114)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$notInState$3(StateTransitionController.java:143)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.notInState(StateTransitionController.java:139)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.withProjectsConfigured(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:114)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildToolingModelController.locateBuilderForTarget(DefaultBuildToolingModelController.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator$DefaultBuildTreeModelController.lambda$locateBuilderForTarget$0(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.withToolingModels(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.AbstractBuildState.withToolingModels(AbstractBuildState.java:118)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator$DefaultBuildTreeModelController.locateBuilderForTarget(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator$DefaultBuildTreeModelController.locateBuilderForDefaultTarget(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:68)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getTarget(DefaultBuildController.java:157)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getModel(DefaultBuildController.java:101)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.getModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:113)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.findModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:97)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.findModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.findModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:81)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.findModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.findModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:66)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.findModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.runAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:131)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.beforeTasks(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.beforeTasks(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$fromBuildModel$1(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$5(StateTransitionController.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:247)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$6(StateTransitionController.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:103)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:74)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:65)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:136)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
```

I went back and started over three times, and I can't figure out why it doesn't work. I did everything they said to do. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: I can get my app to compile if I eliminate several of the lines from the kts files. However, when I run it, it crashes with "Default FirebaseApp is not initialized" and asks me to make sure I call FirebaseApp.initializeApp. I added the call, which did not report any error itself, but the "not initialized" message still appears.

Comment: Can you share code of project gradle

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Arul asked for, and please also respond using @.